# Extract src of <img> element (selected by class) from multiple HTML pages

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, web-scraping

Example:

website has url https://images.com/Robots.aspx?ID=xxxx , where xxxx is an integer between 1 and 1935.

On each given page there can be an `<img class="thumbnail" src="Images\Robots\{robotname}.png">`.
Not all pages have this element.

I need to extract all existing {robotname} variants and then download the images, but i'm struggling to understand how i can store the element in an object (Python or JS, for example).

How do i start / what i can read to do it?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('img.thumbnail').forEach(img=>img.src)` should get you on the right path.

Comment: `document` refers to a currently opened page, while i have 1935 page URLs. I need to somehow automate the process (and i don't have access to this site database).

Comment: well then use BeautifulSoup as @fourjr answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python you can use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and extract all img tags `soup.find_all("img")` and manipulate the data from there

Comment: Thanks! I'll look at their documentation.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download each page in a loop with AJAX.
2. Parse the DOM with something like [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom).
3. Use a selector with [`querySelectorAll()`].(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get each image element.
4. Use a regular expression on the image src-attribute to get the robot name. Like: `$img.src.match(/([^\/]+).png$/i)[1]`.
5. Download all the robots with AJAX.
6. Combine robot name and downloaded robot to an object with key value pairs.

Let me know if you need more help or a code example.

Comment: Thank you! When I get home I'll try this method if beatifulsoup would not help/be harder to implement.